# tf.random.normal() doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, eager-execution

I am new on Python and tensorflow. I am a little (or a lot) puzzled: tf.random.normal() doesn't seem to work as expected.

tf.random.normal() is used to generate some data. I want to see the data are generated as expected by printing them on the screen through "tf.keras.backend.eval()".

```
randndata = tf.random.normal([1, 5])
print('randndata = ', tf.keras.backend.eval(randndata))
```

So far, everything seems fine. However, it gives a totally different result if the data are printed for the second time.

```
randndata = tf.random.normal([1, 5])
print('randndata = ', tf.keras.backend.eval(randndata))
print('randndata = ', tf.keras.backend.eval(randndata))
```

The issue is not with the normal distribution only. Uniform distribution has the same issue.

The tensorflow version is 2.1.0.

Thank you!

Comment: I just tested it with TF2.3.0 and found that it prints same numbers twice. Try upgrading your TF.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try to upgrade Tensorflow.

Comment: just tested 2.1 and 2.3 in Colab - both give same line twice. There may be something else.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates this behavior. It should be complete, meaning users can copy, paste, and run it without changing anything.

Comment: This sounds like the difference between eager and graph modes, its not a bug or anything.

Comment: @jakub thank you for your help. As pointed out by Ruslan, it's caused by disabling eager execution.

Answer (score 3):

Garry, I was able to reproduce your error by disabling eager execution. In that case `tf.random.normal` gets called every time you run `eval`.
With eager execution on, random numbers are assigned to the variable immediately and then they are just passed to `tf.keras.backend.eval()` calls.

Find where you might have disabled eager execution - this will explain the puzzling situation. Post more code here, if in doubt.

I suggest to use TF2 style with eager execution and not to call `eval` at all (or call it once if you have some complex calculation graph).
read more on eager execution [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/enable_eager_execution)

Comment: @ Ruslan Thank you so much! I was trying to upgrade Tensorflow version. However, version 2.3.0 seems not available through Conda.  Besides, Ruslan S. also commented that there is no issue with version 2.1.0.

Comment: What was the reason in your case? did it help? if yes - pls accept.

Comment: you are so right. It's caused by disabling eager execution. I will read more on eager execution in your link. Many thanks!